# ¿Por qué no funciona el paso de número como parametros a otro proyecto?

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar este ejercicio  Crea un programa que reciba dos enteros como argumentos y que calcule su suma. A continuación, crea un lanzador que ejecute tres veces el programa con diferentes enteros.
Mi idea es la siguiente, paso a un proyecto 2 números sacados del array args[] que le paso atraves de otro programa.
Este es el proyecto que hará la suma

```
Public class EJ6 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double suma;
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    suma = num1+num2;
    System.out.println("la suma de "+num1 +"y "+num2 +" es: "+suma);
    }

}
```

Este es el otro proyecto que me permite pasarle los parámetros

```
public class EJLanzador {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("introduce un parametro: ");
        String num1 = entrada.nextLine();
        numeros.add(num1);
        System.out.println("introduce otro parametro: ");
        String num2 = entrada.nextLine();
        numeros.add(num2);
        System.out.println("introduce otro parametro: ");
        String num3 = entrada.nextLine();
        numeros.add(num3);
        System.out.println("introduce otro parametro: ");
        String num4 = entrada.nextLine();
        numeros.add(num4);
        System.out.println("introduce otro parametro: ");
        String num5 = entrada.nextLine();
        numeros.add(num5);
        System.out.println("introduce otro parametro: ");
        String num6 = entrada.nextLine();
        numeros.add(num6);
        String comando;
        String s = "";
        Process p;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                comando = "java -jar EJ6.jar"+numeros.get(i)+"" + numeros.get(i + 1);
            } else {
                comando = "java -jar EJ6.jar " + numeros.get(i * 2) + " " + numeros.get(i * 2 + 1);
            }
            try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Que quiere decir que no funciona?

Comment: Pues echo andar el lanzador y no me devuelve los valores de la suma del otro ejercicio

Comment: Hay cosas que sorprenden en tu código, no sé si lo hiciste así por requisito del ejercicio ¿? 1º. Dos métodos `main`... normalmente debería haber un sólo método `main` que por lógica estaría en `EJLanzador`. Desde allí podrías pasar los valores a algún método de `EJ6` que cumpla lo requerido en el enunciado. 2º. ¿Por qué usas `Process, Runtime, BufferedReader` y demás? ¿Por qué no capturas el dato en el Scanner y lo pasas a la clase `EJ6`. Eso sólo se justifica si te lo requieren en el ejercicio para aprender a usar esas clases.

Comment: Si desde proyecto lanzador tengo que llamar java jar EJ6 como lo hago si noi?
Pues si son 2 proyectos debe tener 2 metodos main no?cada proyecto tiene un main

Comment: Y si sacas el catch y te fijas si no hay un error real ahi?

Comment: He depurado y no va al catch pasa del Rutine.get al system.exit

Comment: Dice que no encuentra el archivo pero si esta en C:/ lo he metido yo y lo estoy viendo

Comment: Tú puedes llamar `EJ6` haciendo simplemente esto: `EJ6.main(new String[] {"1","2"});` donde `1` y `2` serían los argumentos. Pruébalo a mano sin Scanner no nada y si funciona entonces sólo tienes que recoger los datos con el Scanner y pasarlos de ese modo.

Comment: Eso donde lo meto?en el sitio del comando?

Comment: En el `main` de la clase `EJLanzador` comentando todo el bloque del Scanner y de todo el rollo de `RunTime` y demás. Haz una prueba sencilla sólo con eso y si funciona mete la parte compleja del Scanner.

Comment: el problema es que no me encuentra el archvio, da igual si quito c// y lo meto en el mismo directorio del src del proyecto lanzador

Comment: Tu comando no debería ser así? : "java -jar C:\\EJ6.jar "+num1+" "+num2 ??

Comment: ¿Probaste con `EJ6.main` o no? Ahí no tienes que poner la ruta del archivo ni nada, suponiendo que el CLASSPATH está bien indicado.

Comment: @FernandoOxyde llevas razon pero aun asi no imprime la suma

Answer (score 3):

Tu while está mal, debes iterar sobre **stdInput** para que te imprima el resultado, aparte de los cambios que te mencioné en los comentarios..

```
while((s= stdInput.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: YA lo tenia corregido acabo de editarlo para ver como que veas como lo tengo

Comment: Amigo copié tus códigos y se ejecutan sin ningún problema, solo asegurate de que haya un espacio entre cada parámetro del comando cuando entra al if y también que el archivo EJ6.jar lo puedas ejecutar desde la consola sin problemas

Comment: y te imprime la suma?

Comment: Así es, pide los 6 parámetros e imprime 3 resultados de las sumas

Comment: Listo ya rula gracias, pero solo va si lop meto en C// si lo dejo en src del otro proyecto da error de aceso